# Change Worksheet Name (Excel) via Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I have an challenge that I need to change on a daily basis in a XLSX document the existing sheet name to a new sheet name and than save it

My script looks like this:

```
$xlspath = "C:\Users\roger\Test - Test\Daily_Files\Testfile.xlsx"
$xldoc = new-object -comobject Excel.application
$xldoc.DisplayAlerts = $false
$xldoc.Visible =$false
$workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($xlspath)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$worksheet.name = "Headcount"
$workbook.Save = ($xlspath)
$workbook.Close()
$xldoc.Quit()
```

I always get this error - even so the file gets save and the name has changed:

> ````
> C:\CommonUserData\Roger\Test\Test.ps1:8 char:1
> + $workbook.Save = "C:\Users\roger\Test - Test\Daily_Files\ ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ```
> ````

Does someone have an idea how to solve this or make this a very simple script?

Comment: Probably need to use `.SaveAs`, and there shouldn't be any `=` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the `.Save()` or `.SaveAs()` methods for this. Just close the workbook with parameter `$true`:

```
$xlspath = "C:\Users\roger\Test - Test\Daily_Files\Testfile.xlsx"
$xldoc = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
$xldoc.DisplayAlerts = $false
$xldoc.Visible =$false
$workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($xlspath)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$worksheet.Name = "Headcount"
$workbook.Close($true)   # save the updated workbook
$xldoc.Quit()

# Important: remove references to the used COM objects when finished so they don't keep lingering in memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xldoc)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Hi Theo, sorry for my late response I was on holidays. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you